# Alexa Media Playback Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to create a custom Alexa skill that provides audio playback? I would like to create a skill to play music from a currently unsupported music service. I've search through the API documentation, but have been unsuccessful in finding any mention of it.

Comment: are you talking about having Alexa play music from another source other than Amazon?  like Google Play or iTunes or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon released the Audio Streaming API about two weeks ago. Now you can use playlists. The SDKs unfortunately have not caught up yet, so for now you have to roll your own JSON response.

[ASK Streaming](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills)

Comment: That's awesome news. That's for the update!

Comment: By the way me and my buddies are working on a tool that we built specifically for prototyping skills. https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development

Requests and responses from Alexa will be sent directly to your development laptop, so that you can quickly code and debug without having to do any deployments. We have found this to be very useful for our own development.

Our Github project is here: https://github.com/bespoken/bst

We are also adding other useful commands for Alexa development.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon supports rich media playback. The announcement for this with lots of details is [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills).

For simpler stuff, there is another feature that lets you provide audio playback called [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference). Follow that link to a description of how to use it.

For SSML, in summary, you can supply up to 5 MP3 files in a very specific format with a total of 90 seconds worth of playback audio. This probably isn't good enough to do what you want (unless you like very short songs) but it is what is supported by the platform and the only way, currently, for an Alexa skill to play anything.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa currently has a [audio player](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#play) interface that may fit your needs.

It can launch the normal audio player with a specified audio file, and album image.